# How to use procedure variable in select and insert query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have two variables 
1. inserted_user_id, 
2. inserted_address_id

in my MySQL procedure.

I need to use them in insert queries and select queries. Im trying something like

> insert into user_new(name, company, email, customer_id) select name,
>   company, email, inserted_user_id from user_old;
>
> insert into user_address_map(address_id, user_id) select
>   inserted_user_id,inserted_address_id ;

There two statements are not working. How to use procedure variable's value in the above sql statements?

Answer (score 1):

First make a select to get all the info: (you need to declare these variables first)

```
SELECT name, 
       company, 
       email, 
INTO   varname, varcompany, varemail 
FROM   user_old
```

then use it into insert

```
INSERT INTO user_new 
            (name, 
             company, 
             email, 
             customer_id) 
VALUES      (varname, 
             varcompany, 
             varemail, 
             inserted_user_id);
```

**edit:**
First insert the Selected values and get the id of the inserted row

```
INSERT INTO user_new 
            (name, 
             company, 
             email) 
SELECT name, 
       company, 
       email 
FROM   user_old 

SET out_param = last_insert_id();
```

Then update this row with your param

```
UPDATE user_new 
SET    customer_id = inserted_user_id 
WHERE  id = out_param;
```

Comment: Actually i have huge column list in the select statement. And the stored procedure includes many such tables. If i create variables for each column it will become more than 1000 variables. It will be tough to handle. Is there any alternative approach for this?

Comment: that case try to merge it all: `insert into user_new select name as name, company as company, email as email, inserted_user_id as customer_id from user_old);` or something like, found in here [link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/422460-sql-insert-into-values-select.html)

Comment: If i use inserted_user_id in a select statement it compiles but fails in run time.

Comment: what error give you ? are you shure its hav the value u whant?

Comment: another way its to insert the values from select first, and after that update de last inserted row with inserted_user_id. I change the answer to show it

Comment: My procedure breaks at the update statement and hits exception handler. Show Warnings prints Empty set (0.00 sec).

Comment: I added the stored procedure what im writing in http://noblogdeffound.blogspot.in/2014/01/mysql-procedure.html

Comment: i just give a lock to it and: where do u fill insert_contact_id  with values?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. I marked a line in red. Just about that. http://noblogdeffound.blogspot.in/2014/01/mysql-procedure.html

Comment: There is a statement  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into insert_contact_id;

Comment: you need to run LAST_INSERT_ID() just after the insert, if you run another query after insert and before LAST_INSERT_ID() it wont work (i think) check [mysql_ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/information-functions.html) for more info.

Comment: Thats not the problem. I changed and tried again. Even the select statement works. select insert_contact_id, insert_mkt_cnt_id prints the expected values. Some problem with insert/update. Thank you so much for all the help.